# Angular e HTML - Não consigo mostrar as informações do banco no HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

Gostaria de mostrar as informações do banco, está puxando corretamente as informações,e é mostrado no console que há um array de 35 itens a ser mostrado mas não estou conseguindo exibi-las no html.

```
<div ng-app="Chamados" ng-controller="Chamando">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="chamado in CHAMADOS">
            <td>{{chamado.STATUS}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("Chamados", []);
app.controller("Chamando", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('caminhodoBanco'/*, JSON.stringify(data)*/).then(function (response) {
        $scope.chamados = response.data.records;
    }, function (response) {

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Esta em caixa alta `CHAMADOS` em vez de baixa, como está na linha `$scope.chamados` mas você poderia editar sua pergunta e explicar realmente sua dificuldade, pois esta vaga, não da pra saber exatamente seu problema.

Comment: Ainda sim não mudou em nadakkk

Comment: Veja o que está retornando no `Console`, você esta tentando retornar as informações diretamente do *Banco de Dados* ?

Comment: {CHAMADOS: Array(35)}

Comment: ele consegue pegar as informações do banco de dados, mas não consigo exibir elas no html

Comment: Abaixo da linha `$scope.chamados = ` faz um `console.log($scope.chamados); `

Comment: não apresentou nenhuma mudança

Comment: Na verdade queremos saber qual eh a saida de `console.log`, nao ira apresentar alguma diferenca @ThiagoLuizFerreiraTavares. Pode nos apresentar qual foi a saida, ou a saida de `response.data.records`?

Comment: {CHAMADOS: Array(35)}
CHAMADOS
:
(35) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Tente isso @ThiagoLuizFerreiraTavares: `$scope.chamados = response.data.records.CHAMADOS;`

Comment: Tentei e deu isso no console @Lucas Costa

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CHAMADOS' of undefined
    at historico:66
    at angular.js:16832
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17971)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18269)
    at l (angular.js:12387)
    at XMLHttpRequest.A.onload (angular.js:12541) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"